# Delete Datagridview rows as well as in my access database vb.net

Tags: vb.net

this is my code for loading the data in my database going to my datagrid

```
Private Sub Records_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Database3.Accdb;"
        Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim tables As DataTableCollection
        Dim source1 As New BindingSource
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [userinfo] ORDER BY ID", MyConn) 'Change items to your database name
        da.Fill(ds, "userinfo") 'Change items to your database name
        Dim cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        DataGridView1.DataSource = view
    End Sub
```

and this is my delete button to delete a selected row in datagrid but the whole table is deleted instead (i know this cause i put it to delete the whole table just to know my sql is working)

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Database3.Accdb;"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    Dim row As New Integer
    Try
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = (ds.Tables)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Delete * from [userinfo]", MyConn)
        da.Fill(ds, "userinfo")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

i want to delete a selected row in my datagrid. thank you in advance

Comment: `Delete * from [userinfo] ` will delete everything in the table. Pass your ID to be deleted. Eg. `Delete * from [userinfo] where ID=5`

Comment: thanks but how can i know what row in my datagrid is going to be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Delete * from [userinfo]` will delete everything in the table. Pass your ID to be deleted. Eg. `Delete * from [userinfo] where ID=5`

You can use [Datagridview.SelectedRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property to find the selected Rows. Pass the ID Column index and you will get the ID.

Eg.
`"Delete * from [userinfo] where ID=" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()`

If you Allow Multi-Select, Loop through the rows to delete. 
Also use [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to pass variables to queries for security purposes.

Comment: wow it works. thank you very much for the help. yes i will use paramaters to  avoid injections. thank you very much again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad English. 
Step 1: Listen to click on a Datagrid

```
Private Sub datagridview_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles datagridview.CellClick
```

Step 2: Get what column click

```
datagridview.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
```

Step 3: Delete from Database

```
Dim sqlcmd As String = "delete  from [userinfo] where YourColumn = '" & datagridview.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value & "'"
```

Fully code:

```
Private Sub Datagridview_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellClick
        Try
            Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
            Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Database3.Accdb;"
            MyConn = New OleDbConnection
            Dim cmdstr As String = "delete * from [userinfo] where YourColumn = '" & DataGridView.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value & "'"
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdstr, MyConn)
            MyConn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MyConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to refer to deleted row values is row original value from deleted rows table:

```
dt is datasource of datagridview
Dim dtDelete As DataTable = dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GridValue", r("Gridcolumn", DataRowVersion.Original))
```

the example is SQL but method is not specific